# How to make select button like Apple Pages app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I can select multiple font styles in Apple Pages app, orange colored box on the screen.

How to make it?

I can't find any ui component in the iOS SDK like this, multiple select. `UISegmentControl` is only for one select like radio button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use a UISegmentControl in momentary mode to have the bar :)

set custom background images for the cells

there is no stock control but this is quite basic using this approach

Comment: Yep, it is unfortunately true. This UI-look, is not available in the SDK. You could look around and try to find an image that works in the cells similar to this, but I doubt you will find one. If you have decent photo-editing skills, then perhaps you could make one yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to do multiple selections simultaneously using uisegmenrcontroller? Uisegmenrcontroller reflects only one selection at a time

Comment: it is only possible to have MOMENTARY STYLE=no selection

Answer (score 0):

No default thing is available you have to do it by yourself. You set tags for each button and only one selector. By checking the selected button tags execute you specific code.

Answer (score 0):

For that, yon need to take UISegment Control and make it's background images custom. Also you can set the width of the each segment.

Then you will achieve your goal.

Cheers!